# Implemented code into large workbook and Loop through is doing some funky stuff Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

First off, I am very new to vba and got help writing these macros so please bear with me.

I have two macros, the first one, in theory, is supposed to add a new row to a table when the table fills up so additional data can be entered and the second macro, in theory, is supposed to delete those additional rows as data gets taken out of them so the table does not grow too large with empty rows.

The workbook has 32 sheets. 26 of those sheets are user interacted and, of those 26, each sheet has 3 tables for a total of 78 tables.

First macro:
What it's supposed to do: When the user is entering data in 1 of the 3 tables on their specific sheet and they enter an amount in the last row (not including total row) a new row is supposed to appear allowing them to continue entering data and the formula fills down.

What it's actually doing: Whenever I click anywhere in the table it automatically adds two new rows and does not fill down the data and, for that matter, it adds the rows into the middle of the table and does this for each table on that specific sheet.

Second macro: 
What it's supposed to do: It's in a module and I have it set up on save. It loops through each table in the workbook deleting rows that do not contain data. It's a call in `ThisWorkbook` but it's not doing it on save.

First macro

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sht As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

'Declaration of Variables
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim tbl As ListObject

For Each tbl In Sht.ListObjects

'Set Lastrow
LastRow = tbl.Range.Rows.Count
LastRow = LastRow + tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row - 1

'Check - is someone entering in account name for the last open row
If Sht.Range("B" & LastRow - 1) = "" Then 'User is not entering in account name in last open row
'do nothing
Else 'User is entering in account name in last open row - create new row
Application.EnableEvents = False 'turn off event handlers which allows sub to execute
'UNPROTECT SHEET CODE HERE
tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count).Insert
Intersect(Sht.Range("B:L"), tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count)).Insert
'PROTECT SHEET CODE HERE
Application.EnableEvents = True 'turn on event handlers
End If

Next tbl

End Sub
```

Here is the second macro

```
Sub Delete_Table_Rows()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim i As Long
Dim rowCount As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects

'How many rows in the table?
rowCount = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

'Error checking
If rowCount < 3 Then
'Not enough rows in table to do anything
Exit Sub
End If

'Since we're deleting rows, we'll loop backwards
For i = rowCount - 2 To 1 Step -1
'Using Client column as reference point, it goes row by row
'And Resizes to be 4 cells wide when it looks for blank cells
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(i).Resize(1, 4)) = 0 Then
    'UNPROTECT SHEET CODE HERE
    tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(i).Delete
    'PROTECT SHEET CODE HERE
End If
Next i

Next tbl
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a single column of tables aligned down the side of each worksheet, this should do what you want.  Whenever the last row of column 'B' of a table is non-empty it will insert a new row in the table.  Note that this should work for cases where you have a number of tables stacked above each other with varying #s of columns.  It will ensure there's a minimum of at least one empty row between tables.  The way this works is that when it detects a table below it (ie column 'B' cell 2 rows down is in a table) and is about to expand the table to occupy this empty row, it will insert a blank row so that a one row buffer between tables is maintained.  So my update for your first macro is this:

```
Public Function IsCellInTable(rng As Range) As Boolean
  IsCellInTable = Not rng.ListObject Is Nothing
End Function


Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sht As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim LastRow As Long
  Dim tbl As ListObject

  For Each tbl In Sht.ListObjects

    LastRow = tbl.ListRows(tbl.ListRows.Count).Range.Row

    If Sht.Range("B" & LastRow) <> "" Then
     Application.enableEvents = False
      If IsCellInTable(Rows(LastRow + 2).Cells(1, 2)) Then
        Rows(LastRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert
      End If
      tbl.ListRows.Add alwaysinsert:=False
     Application.enableEvents = True
    End If

  Next tbl

End Sub
```

In order to trigger your 'Delete_Table_Rows' subroutine just prior to a save you should call it in 'Workbook_BeforeSave' like this:

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  Delete_Table_Rows
End Sub
```

Note that your delete routine won't work if the tables in a worksheet have a differing # of columns.  To make it work in the latter case you should change this row:

```
tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(i).Delete
```

to this:

```
tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
```